# Non-blocking Loading Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having some issues implementing a non blocking loading window. This is what the requirements specify.

[image]

Basically every time there is a loading event this window should appear on top while being modal, and then when it receives the loading complete event it should hide the window again. I've seen many suggestions to use overlays. However we have way to many windows and dialogs so doing that for all of them is simply impractical.

This was my first stab. Issue is if I don't call ShowDialog and use show instead the window appears but its white, completely blank. If I use ShowDialog the window is there forever since it is thread blocking.

```
public partial class MetroProgressWindow : MetroWindow, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _message;
    private bool _isRunning;

    private static MetroProgressWindow _instance;

    public static MetroProgressWindow Instance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new MetroProgressWindow();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    private MetroProgressWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // register event listener
        Messenger.Default.Register<ProgressIndicatorEvent>(this, OnReceivedMessage);
    }

    private void OnReceivedMessage(ProgressIndicatorEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Type == ProgressIndicatorEvent.ProgressIndicatorEventTypes.START)
        {
            Message = e.Message;
            _isRunning = true;
            this.Show();
            // this.ShowDialog was causing app to hang because thread blocking
        }
        else
        {
            Message = null;
            _isRunning = false;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        private set
        {
            _message = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Can this be achieved using multiple UI threads? I've seen that is discouraged but in this case since I'm not updating data or anything I wouldn't think it was a big deal.

Comment: I would pass the action, which should be executed while displaying the Load-Window, as parameter to the Load-Window. So that the Load-Window can execute the action in a background-tread and when the action is finished, the Load-Dialog would disapear and your result is there

Comment: @Tomtom is it possible to make it generic enough to execute any action, it one case it might be loading data from the database, in another it might be generating a PDF report

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just pass an object of type `Action` or `Action<object>` if you need arguments.